# phpMyAdmin - Error. Ошибка при установке

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, apache2, termux

Значит дело такое, установил я апач на Termux, всё работает, решил установить WordPress.
Следовал гайду, дошёл до установки phpMyAdmin, закинул в директорию файлы. Запускаю сайт, и тут ошибка:

Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: )

[image: Скриншот ошибки:]

Облазил уже весь гугл, ничего не нашёл. Вроде кто то говорил что проблема в php.ini, вот только у меня нет этого файла. В phpinfo(); я нашёл директорию где он должен лежать, его там нет, и он так же не загружен в сам phpinfo();, я его создал и отконфигурировал как тот человек, но увы, он его не видит.
Я новичок в это теме, создаю эту хрень в первый раз, так что прошу не сильно смеятся надо мной)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в параметре php - [session.save_path](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)

Нужно найти в php.ini параметр

session.save_path = “/tmp”

и указать корректное значение

В данный момент сессия не может запуститься, т.к. указано некорректный путь к директории